# 400 Error: redirect_uri_mismatch for yotube video upload

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth

I am implementing functionality for uploading video's to a YouTube channel from [here](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-authenticate-upload-videos-to-youtube-channel-in-php_974.html).

I set up my Google Developer console environment exactly like suggested.

[image]

I also use the same client Id and client secret that it gave me. When I run the script it returns with an error.

> 400. That’s an error. Error: redirect_uri_mismatch Application: Localhost You can email the developer of this application at: XXXXX@gmail.com
>        The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost/youtube/index.php did not match a registered redirect URI.

Request Details

```
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
response_type=code
access_type=online
redirect_uri=http://localhost/youtube/index.php
pageId=none
approval_prompt=auto
state=2067416475
client_id=xxxxxx68kc7csrag9as2o3lv70k0spa6hfb1ofs4.apps.googleusercontent
```

I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect URI in the Google developers console states

> One URI per line. Needs to have a protocol, no URL fragments, and no
>   relative paths. Can't be a public IP Address.

You have set yours to

```
http://localhost/youtube
```

you should set it to

```
http://localhost/youtube/index.php
```

Redirect URI must be set to the path to the exact file which will handle the authentication.

**Note:**
Also you will now want to delete that one because you need to keep your client id and client secret private you just shared it with everyone.

Comment: Deleting it isn't necessary since you can just reset the secret.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar problem, and wanted to note that updating the google api console and that change being present can take some time. Generally only a few minutes but sometimes it seems longer.